# Can not add SeekBar to MediaPlayer.

Tags: android-mediaplayer, runnable, seekbar, android-seekbar

I have tried Runnable as well but of no use. Here is my code, What can be done here?
I have used Parecelable method to get my currently selected song from main activity to this playscreen activity.Now I want to attach seekbar to that 'currsong' I received when my mediaplayer mPlayer starts

```
package com.musicplayer;

import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;


public class PlayScreen extends ActionBarActivity {

private Song currsong;
public MainActivity mainActivity;
private MediaPlayer mPlayer;
public TextView songTitle , songArtist;
public ImageView playPause, next, prev;
public SeekBar seekbar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_screen);
    currsong = (Song)getIntent().getParcelableExtra("currSong");
    final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.playScreen);
    Drawable drawable=new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), currsong.getAlbumart(getApplicationContext()));
    relativeLayout.setBackground(drawable);
    songTitle=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.stitle);
    songArtist=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.artist);
    playPause= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.playPause);
    next= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.next);
    prev= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.prev);
    seekbar=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.progress);

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mPlayer.isPlaying()){
                mPlayer.stop();
                try {
                    mPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            mainActivity.songPos++;
            currsong=mainActivity.songList.get(mainActivity.songPos);
            Drawable drawable=new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), currsong.getAlbumart(getApplicationContext()));
            relativeLayout.setBackground(drawable);
            seekbar.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration());
            playSong();
        }
    });
    prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mPlayer.isPlaying()){
                mPlayer.stop();
                try {
                    mPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            mainActivity.songPos--;
            currsong=mainActivity.songList.get(mainActivity.songPos);
            Drawable drawable=new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), currsong.getAlbumart(getApplicationContext()));
            relativeLayout.setBackground(drawable);
            seekbar.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration());
            playSong();
        }
    });
    playPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if(mPlayer.isPlaying() ){
                mPlayer.pause();
                playPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
            }
            else {
                mPlayer.start();
                playPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                }

        }
    });

    playSong();


}


public void playSong(){

    mPlayer= new MediaPlayer();
    mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    songTitle.setText(currsong.getTitle());
    songArtist.setText(currsong.getArtist());
    //set uri
    Uri trackUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,currsong.getID());
    //set the data source

    try{
        mPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), trackUri);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("MUSIC SERVICE", "Error setting data source", e);
    }
    try {
        mPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    //seekbar.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration());
    mPlayer.start();
    playPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);



}






public void initMusicPlayer(){
    //set player properties
    mPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(),
            PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener((MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener) this);
    mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener((MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener) this);
    mPlayer.setOnErrorListener((MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener) this);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_play_screen, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Searching a lot i have figured out a way to do this and since no one ha answered this question so to help others with same problem I am providing my solved java file code below-

```
package com.musicplayer;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.StaticLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;


public class PlayScreen extends ActionBarActivity implements Runnable,
    OnClickListener, OnSeekBarChangeListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

protected static Song currsong ;
protected TextView songTitle , songArtist;
protected ImageView playPause, next, prev, loop ,shuffle;
protected SeekBar seekbar;
protected RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
protected Uri trackpath;
protected static boolean looping=false, shuffling=false;
protected ArrayList<Song> shuffleSong;
protected MediaPlayerSingleton mPlayer = MediaPlayerSingleton.getInstance();
protected ArrayList<Song> songList;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_screen);
    currsong = (Song)getIntent().getParcelableExtra("currSong");
    songList =new ArrayList<Song>();
    Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    songList = b.getParcelableArrayList("categories");
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.playScreen);
    Drawable drawable=new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), currsong.getAlbumart(getApplicationContext()));
    relativeLayout.setBackground(drawable);
    songTitle=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.stitle);
    songArtist=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.artist);
    playPause= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.playPause);
    next= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.next);
    prev= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.prev);
    loop = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.loop);
    shuffle = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.shuffle);
    seekbar=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.progress);
    next.setOnClickListener(this);
    prev.setOnClickListener(this);
    playPause.setOnClickListener(this);
    loop.setOnClickListener(this);
    shuffle.setOnClickListener(this);
    seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    seekbar.setEnabled(true);
    loop.setImageResource(R.drawable.loop);
    shuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.shuffle);
    shuffleSong = new ArrayList<Song>();

    playSong();
}

public void getSongList() {
    shuffleSong.addAll(songList);
    Collections.shuffle(shuffleSong);
}


public void playSong(){
    mPlayer.reset();
    int minute = 60*1000;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't play this song: "+ currsong.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    TextView totaltime =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeleft);

    //set uri
    Uri trackUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,currsong.getID());
    trackpath=trackUri;
    //set the data source

    try{
        mPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), trackUri);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("MUSIC SERVICE", "Error setting data source", e);
    }
    try {
        mPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't play this song: "+ currsong.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        next.performClick();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't play this song: "+ currsong.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        next.performClick();
    }
    songTitle.setText(currsong.getTitle());
    songArtist.setText(currsong.getArtist());
    seekbar.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration());
    seekbar.setEnabled(true);

    new Thread(this).start();
    if(mPlayer.getDuration()<minute) {
        totaltime.setText(String.format("0:%1$tS", new Date(mPlayer.getDuration()-60*1000*30)));
    }else{
        totaltime.setText(String.format("%1$tM:%1$tS", new Date(mPlayer.getDuration()-60*1000*30)));
    }
    mPlayer.start();
    playPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
    mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_play_screen, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.equals(playPause)){
        if(mPlayer == null){
            try{
                mPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), trackpath);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("MUSIC SERVICE", "Error setting data source", e);
            }
            try {
                mPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            seekbar.setEnabled(true);
        }
        if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.pause();
            playPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
        }
        else {
            mPlayer.start();
            playPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
            seekbar.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration());
            new Thread(this).start();
        }
    }
    if(v.equals(next) && mPlayer != null){
        if(shuffling==false) {
            if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mPlayer.stop();
                try {
                    mPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (looping == true) {
                if (AllSongs.songPos == songList.size() - 1) {
                    AllSongs.songPos = 0;
                    currsong = songList.get(AllSongs.songPos);
                } else {
                    AllSongs.songPos++;
                    currsong = songList.get(AllSongs.songPos);
                }
            } else {
                if (AllSongs.songPos == songList.size() - 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "List Ended", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //currsong=mainActivity.songList.get(mainActivity.songPos);
                } else {
                    AllSongs.songPos++;
                    currsong = songList.get(AllSongs.songPos);
                }
            }
        }else{
            if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mPlayer.stop();
                try {
                    mPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            /*Random rand = new Random();
            int randomNum = mainActivity.songPos;
            while(randomNum==mainActivity.songPos) {
                randomNum = rand.nextInt(shuffleSong.size());
            }
            currsong = shuffleSong.get(randomNum);
            shuffleSong.remove(randomNum);*/
            if (looping == true) {
                if (AllSongs.songPos == shuffleSong.size() - 1) {
                    AllSongs.songPos = 0;
                    currsong = shuffleSong.get(AllSongs.songPos);
                } else {
                    AllSongs.songPos++;
                    currsong = shuffleSong.get(AllSongs.songPos);
                }
            } else {
                if (AllSongs.songPos == shuffleSong.size() - 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "List Ended", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //currsong=mainActivity.songList.get(mainActivity.songPos);
                } else {
                    AllSongs.songPos++;
                    currsong = shuffleSong.get(AllSongs.songPos);
                }
            }

        }


        Drawable drawable=new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), currsong.getAlbumart(getApplicationContext()));
        relativeLayout.setBackground(drawable);
        seekbar.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration());
        seekbar.setProgress(0);
        playSong();
    }
    if(v.equals(prev) && mPlayer != null){
        if(shuffling==false) {
            if(mPlayer.isPlaying()){
                mPlayer.stop();
                try {
                    mPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (looping == true) {
                if (AllSongs.songPos == 0) {
                    AllSongs.songPos = songList.size() - 1;
                    currsong = songList.get(AllSongs.songPos);
                } else {
                    AllSongs.songPos--;
                    currsong = songList.get(AllSongs.songPos);
                }
            } else {
                if (AllSongs.songPos == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "List Ended", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    AllSongs.songPos--;
                    currsong = songList.get(AllSongs.songPos);
                }
            }
        }else{
            if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mPlayer.stop();
                try {
                    mPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (looping == true) {
                if (AllSongs.songPos == 0) {
                    AllSongs.songPos = shuffleSong.size() - 1;
                    currsong = shuffleSong.get(AllSongs.songPos);
                } else {
                    AllSongs.songPos--;
                    currsong = shuffleSong.get(AllSongs.songPos);
                }
            } else {
                if (AllSongs.songPos == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "List Ended", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    AllSongs.songPos--;
                    currsong = shuffleSong.get(AllSongs.songPos);
                }
            }
            /*Random rand = new Random();
            int randomNum = mainActivity.songPos;
            while(randomNum==mainActivity.songPos) {
                randomNum = rand.nextInt(shuffleSong.size());
            }
            currsong = shuffleSong.get(randomNum);
            shuffleSong.remove(randomNum);*/
        }

        Drawable drawable=new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), currsong.getAlbumart(getApplicationContext()));
        relativeLayout.setBackground(drawable);
        seekbar.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration());
        seekbar.setProgress(0);
        playSong();

    }
    if(v.equals(loop)){
        if(looping==false) {
            loop.setImageResource(R.drawable.loopactive);
            looping = true;
        }
        else{
            looping=false;
            loop.setImageResource(R.drawable.loop);
        }
    }
    if(v.equals(shuffle)){
        if(shuffling==false) {
            getSongList();
            shuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.shuffleactive);
            shuffling = true;
            Collections.shuffle(shuffleSong);
            //setNextSongDetails();
            //shuffleList();
        }else{
            shuffleSong.clear();
            shuffling=false;
            shuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.shuffle);
            //setNextSongDetails();
        }
    }
}

/*private void shuffleList() {
    for(int i=0;i<mainActivity.songList.size();i++){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((mainActivity.songList.size() - i)) + i;
        int j=0,k=0;
        int flag=0;
        k=mainActivity.posList.size();
        for(j=0;j<k;j++){

            if(MainActivity.posList.get(j) == randomNum){
                flag=1;
            }
            //j=j+1;
        }
        if(flag==1){
            i=i-1;
        }else{
            MainActivity.posList.add(new Integer(randomNum));
            tempsong=MainActivity.songList.get(randomNum);
            shuffleSong.add(new Song(tempsong.getID(), tempsong.getTitle(), tempsong.getArtist(), tempsong.getAlbumID()));
        }
    }
}*/

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    try {
        if (mPlayer.isPlaying() || mPlayer != null) {
            if (fromUser)
                mPlayer.seekTo(progress);
        } else if (mPlayer == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Media is not running",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            seekBar.setProgress(0);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Log.e("seek bar", "" + e);
        seekBar.setEnabled(false);

    }

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}

@Override
public void run() {
    int currentPosition = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    int total = mPlayer.getDuration();


    while (mPlayer != null && currentPosition < total) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            currentPosition = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return;
        }
        seekbar.setProgress(currentPosition);
    }


}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    if(mPlayer.getCurrentPosition()>0){
        mp.reset();
        next.performClick();
    }

}

}
```